# ASP.NET MVC ModelState is always valid with Fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, fluentvalidation

I am trying to use fluent validation with ASP.NET MVC project. I am trying to validate my view model.

This is my viewmodel,

```
[Validator(typeof(ProductCreateValidator))]
public class ProductCreate
{
    public string ProductCategory   { get; set; }
    public string ProductName       { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

This is my validator class,

```
public class ProductCreateValidator : AbstractValidator<ProductCreate> 
{
    public ProductCreateValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(product => product.ProductCategory).NotNull();
        RuleFor(product => product.ProductName).NotNull();
    }
}
```

And in my controller, I am checking whether my ModelState is valid or not,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductCreate model)
{
    /* This is a method in viewmodel that fills dropdownlists from db */
    model.FillDropDownLists();

    /* Here this is always valid */
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SaveProduct(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

This is what I have. My problem is `ModelState.IsValid` returns `true` when my viewmodel is completely empty. Do i need to manually configure Fluent validation so that model errors can be added to ModalState ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) explains, make sure you have added the following line in your `Application_Start` in order to swap the data annotations model metadata provider and use fluent validation instead:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

Also the following comment in your action scares me:

```
/* This is a method in viewmodel that fills dropdownlists from db */
model.FillDropDownLists();
```

A View model shouldn't know what a database means. So having such methods in your **view model** is a very wrong approach.

Comment: ty very much. About viewmodels, I have several dropdownlists in my view and I want them to be filled from db. What approach can I follow to fill those alternative to my current ?

Comment: I simple approach would be to have a presenter called by the controller. The presenter have the responsibility to making call to the database for creating the viewmodel and filling lists. In a more complex scenario, you could also have a mapper to create a viewmodel from a model or a model from a viewmodel. In all cases, the viewmodel should only know about itself while following the POCO pattern where only primitive types are referencing.